# Disable compass in Zen subtheme

Tags: theming

I am using a [Zen](https://drupal.org/project/zen) subtheme with Sass. I am using CodeKit to compile the Sass into CSS. In my workflow, I enjoy using CodeKit's visual system for project settings because then I can use autoprefixer and souremaps etc easily.

[Zen](https://drupal.org/project/zen) comes with Compass support out of the box. In CodeKit, settings for the styles.scss file is disabled, saying "To change options & output paths for Sass files in a Compass project, you must edit the Compass 'config.rb' file directly."

I could find no way to edit the file to make it behave the way I want, so I want to disable Compass completely.

I tried deleting the lines which seemed related with Compass from the sass files, deleting the config.rb but there seems to be a setting somewhere which I cannot find. I checked out the project settigns in CodeKit but could not find a 'switch' to turn Compass off.

In short, how can I take Compass out of [Zen](https://drupal.org/project/zen)'s css system and use CodeKit to fine tune the compile settings?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any dependencies on Compass? Compass is in the first place a library of Sass mixins and functions. If you disable Compass, your  scss code may fail to compile.

Comment: @marcvangend - I don't. The theme uses it in some parts but I can live without them. In the comments of the config.rb file it says "If you are not using Compass, you may safely ignore or delete this file." so I think it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Zen uses zen grids for its grid (in some cases) and that has a requirement for compass/css2/images. if you aren't using zen grids, you can disable that dependency.

Another option could be that you can try to delete/rename the `config.rb` file entirely, as CodeKit may see that and automatically assume you want to use compass to compile your Sass.

A third possibility could be that in the bottom of `_init.scss` `(STARTERKIT/sass/)` it pulls in zen, along with alot of other compass extensions. try disabling zen along with the others you already disabled.